# GAE Task Queue no longer passes payload to web2py function

Tags: google-app-engine, web2py, task-queue

This code has been working for a couple of years but, for an unknown reason 
to me, has stopped working.

This function continues to create Tasks correctly.

```
def send_task():
        from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
        json_data = ...
        task = taskqueue.Task(url=..., countdown=2, payload=json_data)
        task.add()
```

The handling url is passed to:

```
in db.py
openings_service = Service()


in controller...
@openings_service.json
def opening_task_queue():
    body_data = request.body.getvalue()
```

For the last couple of years `body_data` was populated and processing 
continued.
But last week, without change to my code, request.body was no longer 
present.

I had been running with Web2py R-2.14.6 but an upgrade to R-2.15.0b2 broke 
how I needed to declare functions. Trying R-2.15.4 didn't help, nor R-2.18.5

In the function handling the Google task that historically worked) the value of `request.body` is:

```
<open file '<fdopen>', mode 'w+b' at 0x2b31c3ed9930>
```

Previously this contained the json payload. But `<fdopen>` has me at a loss.